# Exp:resso / FedEx: Shipping methods empty when order is over 4 items

Tags: expresso-store

I'm using the FedEx extension for shipping methods/rates. However, when the cart exceeds 4 items, the shipping method options are empty. There is no {error:shipping_method} displayed when this occurs. Are there limits on the number of items or weight that the FedEx extension will calculate? Or do these limitations possibly exist in the FedEx API?

In the FedEx Rate API docs there is an error described as "660: Weight exceeds limit allowed" which leads me to believe that this may be caused by limitations within the API itself.

Answer (score 1):

Fedex as a whole has a weight limit for items they deliver, so I imagine the rate API reflects those limits. A quick Google search says that the limit is 150lbs.

Is your cart weight over 150?

Comment: Yes, it is possible for the cart to exceed 150 lbs. With the exception of someone selling feathers, oxygen or something of the like, it is possible for any cart to exceed 150 lbs ;) My question is a leading one: should't an error be present in the {error:shipping_method} tag if that is, in fact, the cause of this issue? That being said, this question might get yanked since it's turning into a feature request or bug report.

Comment: Actually, I just created a test product that weights 1 lb and after adding only 13 items, the shipping_method field is emtpy.

Comment: Which services do you have selected? I really think this might be a Fedex thing. (And yes, I agree better error handling is in order.. and last I heard from Adrian, it is coming)

Comment: The services were dictated by the client's warehouse personel and they are Ground, 2 Day, Overnight, Overnight Priority. I tried selecting others just to experiment while referencing the FedEx shipping guidelines and it definitely seems like the services are being filtered based on dimension/weight. For example, the length max for Ground is 108" and, sure enough, I added 108 of a test product of 1" length and Ground showed up. Add one more, and it goes away. I'm gonna take a stab at modifying the extension myself for better error handling.